# Zingchart weird stepped plotting

Tags: plot, charts, linechart, zingchart

I am experiencing some weird plotting by Zingchart. I am trying to plot a smooth curve as it can seen in the Excel graph below.

[image]

However, when using the same input data on Zingchart, some weird [stepped chunks](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GraNXo) are produced. Is this a problem of Zingchart or have I made a mistake in the configuration?

```
var chartData = {
    type: "line",
    plot: {
        aspect: "spline"
    },
  series: [  // Insert your series data here.
      {
            "values":[[0.008376349,-9.167595],
            [0.008375615,59.43667],
            [0.008374971,103.23595],
            [0.008374511,-168.06818],
            [0.008374427,-249.25804],
            [0.008375174,125.39198],
            [0.008376393,-355.0086],
            [0.008377762,-130.61668],
            [0.008379059,298.63593],
.....
               [0.009247098,-15090.601],
                [0.009836536,-4773.134]],
                "text":"A/B"
            }
      ]
    };
    zingchart.render({ // Render Method[3]
      id: "chartDiv",
      data: chartData,
      height: 400,
      width: '100%'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the excellent response time of Zingchart support who guided me on the answer, it seems that the solution is to change the plot type:

```
plot: {
aspect: "segmented"
},
```